# Javascript cannot select element after append with ajax

Tags: javascript, append

The workflow is like this:
I receive with ajax a json that will append a div in the page with a download link.
At the download link i need to detect mousedown which works if i append before the ajax but that isn't possible.
I think is possible to feed the script with the append but i don't feel that is the right way.
A jsfiddle link with a simpler version http://jsfiddle.net/futf53ec/

```
$('a.ajax').mousedown(function(event) {
    $( "<div id=\"download\" class=\"clearfix\"><h2>Album</h2><a class=\"btn\" href=\"#\">Right Click and Save Link As ...</a></div>" ).appendTo( ".placeholder" );
});    
            $('#download a').mousedown(function(event) {
                switch (event.which) {
                    case 1:
                        alert('Confused? Try using the other click button and "Save link as..."');
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        alert('Confused? Try using the right click button and "Save link as..."');
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        //alert('Right Mouse button pressed.');
                        break;
                    default:
                        alert('Hmmm... You have a strange Mouse!');
                }
            });
```

Comment: The link you have looks like regular one so why not using 'click' function instead of 'mousedown'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that $().on() function is what you need:

```
$('a.ajax').mousedown(function(event) {
    $( "<div id=\"download\" class=\"clearfix\"><h2>Album</h2><a class=\"btn\" href=\"#\">Right Click and Save Link As ...</a></div>" ).appendTo( ".placeholder" );
});    
$('.placeholder').on('click', '#download a', function(event) {
//$('#download a').mousedown(
                switch (event.which) {
                    case 1:
                        alert('Confused? Try using the other click button and "Save link as..."');
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        alert('Confused? Try using the right click button and "Save link as..."');
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        //alert('Right Mouse button pressed.');
                        break;
                    default:
                        alert('Hmmm... You have a strange Mouse!');
                }
            });
```

[Js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/futf53ec/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You will need use some late binding to the element, try `live` or `bind` in Jquery to see how late binding work.